# conditions birational morphism is isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two varieties, and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a morphism. Suppose moreover there is a point $Q\in Y$ and $P=f^{-1}(Q)\in X$, such that the restriction $f:X\setminus P\rightarrow Y\setminus Q$ is an isomorphism. So in particular $f$ is a bijective birational morphism.

I was wondering under which conditions $f$ is an isomorphism. It is certainly not true in general. For example if $X$ is the affine line, $Y$ the cusp and $f:X\rightarrow Y: t\mapsto (t^3, t^2)$. Then $f: X\setminus 0\rightarrow Y\setminus (0,0)$ is an isomorphism, but of course $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is not an isomorphism.

Is it true if $X$ and $Y$ are smooth? Or if $X$ and $Y$ are projective?

Comment: Note that in positive characteristic, bijective doesn't imply birational (e.g. the Frobenius morphism).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Projective will not be enough to make it work, because your example of the cusp can also arise for projective curves.

On the other hand, as long as $Y$ is normal and $f$ is proper, then it is true, by a version of Zariski's Main Theorem (Liu, 4.4.3).

**Edit:** As QiL'8 explains, the properness hypothesis is unnecessary. (Perhaps in future I should leave these things to the expert...)

Comment: in fact, this is true without assuming f proper.

Comment: @QiL'8: Yes, I thought so, but couldn't quite put the pieces together in that case. Can you explain?

Comment: because by ZMT, a quasi-finite morphism to a normal noetherian scheme is an open immersion.

Comment: (Quasi-finite _birational_?) Of course!

Comment: Absolutely, thanks.

Comment: I disagree with the second part of edit.